# Jexl - How to check one list contains other list

Tags: jexl

For me, the below logic, single value contains in an array is working perfectly.

```
value = "a"

list1 = ["a","b","c","d"]

value =~ list1
```

But if both are list, as given below, it is not working.

```
list1 = ["a","b","c","d"]

list2 = ["b","c"]
```

How will I check `list2 =~ list1`

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation in JEXL 3.2.1 fixed in JEXL 3.3 (snapshot).
You may overcome it by deriving JexlArithmetic and overriding the 'contains' method which is called when evaluating the 'in/matches' operator.
You may want to look at https://github.com/apache/commons-jexl/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/jexl3/JexlArithmetic.java around line 1610 which will give you a potential solution.